# How to create separate library for include in C++/Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, tinyxml

I've gotten some C++ code to work with the TinyXML parser. However, to do this I had to include the source code from TinyXML with my regular source code. I'd like to have TinyXML included as a separate library. I'm using Eclipse with the Cygwin C++ compiler. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to separate the library from your own project's source code... but you don't know how to build when the library is not in the same folder.

---

Assuming your library has precompiled *.lib and *.h files:

1. Move the library source code to a separate directory
2. Menubar "project"
3. Menu "properties" will open a dialog box for all the project properties there will be a list on the left.
4. List item "C/C++ Build" will change the GUI and show you all the options for gcc's compiler/linker/assembler ( I never do assembly... so I never do anything with the assembler ). [1]
5. GCC C Compiler --> Directories: 
   [image]
6. Green plus icon [2] --> Specify the path of your *.h files
7. Your compiler should now be happy ( but you will fail linking because the linker doesn't know what the actual definitions of each function are )
8. GCC C Linker --> Libraries: 
   [image]
9. Library search path (-L) --> Green plus icon --> Specify the path of your *.lib files
10. Libraries (-l) --> Green plus icon --> Specify the name of each library you are using
11. Your linker should now be happy and your code should compile

[Footnote - 1] The GUI C/C++ build pane is a wrapper for gcc's command line compiler/linker... it is just making it easier to use because it shows you everything visually.

[Footnote - 2] The '+' icon is what will tell the compiler where your libraries *.h include files are located. The compiler needs the *.h files to know what function prototypes your library has before it compiles.

---

Assuming you have the actual ( not compiled ) *.c and *.h:

1. Do the same steps above except in step 7.
2. At step 7. you need to make sure the library's *.c files are seen by Eclipse's "managed make". If it doesn't see the source code then you need to specify where the source is so that it will compile it.

Comment: At the moment, I don't have Eclipse on this computer... and I don't remember exactly what that Eclipse option is... but I will edit my answer as soon as I get to a computer with Eclipse. 

In the mean time others can feel free to chip in.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically easy.  You compile your source code for the library, and construct the library with *ar(1)*.  Yes, surprise, a library is just an archive; UNIX is cool that way.

You can then include the code as a static library when you build the final code.

I don't use Eclipse all that much so I can't tell you the exact process within the IDE, but I believe what you need is to set up a separate project to build it.

Now, if what you want is to build a DLL, then you need to use some special flags.  There's a nice page [here](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html).